# Label Not Generating For All Value In Scatter Plot D3js

Tags: d3.js, label

I Had Created A Scatter Plot Which Takes Json Data From 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FreeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/cyclist-data.json
Every Thing Is Working Fine But Label Is Not Generating For All Values
[image]

My Code Looks Like

```js
var url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FreeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/cyclist-data.json";
//Call CSV Data
d3.json(url, function (error, data) {
    if (error) console.log("You Got Error Some Where !!!");
    /*
     Check For Data
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data[0].Name);
    */
    var fastestTime = 2210;
    data.forEach(function (finish) {
        //turn finishing time into seconds behind winner
        finish.behind = finish.Seconds - fastestTime;
    });
    //Create Margin
    var margin = { top: 40, right: 20, bottom: 60, left: 60 },
        width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    /*
  define scale then followed by axis
  */
    // define x and y scales
    // define x and y scales
    // Formatters for counts and times (converting numbers to Dates).
    var formatCount = d3.format(",.0f"),
        formatTime = d3.time.format("%H:%M"),
        formatMinutes = function (d) { return formatTime(new Date(2012, 0, 1, 0, d)); };
    var xScale = d3.scale.linear().
        domain([d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.behind+50; }), 0 ]).
        range([0, width]);
    var yScale = d3.scale.linear().
        domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.Place + 1; })]).
        range([0, height]);
    // define x axis and y axis
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().
        scale(xScale).
        orient("bottom").
        tickFormat(formatMinutes);
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().
        scale(yScale).
        ticks(8).
        orient("left");
    /*
   Create Tooltip
   */
    var toolTip = d3.tip()
      .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
      .offset([-10, 0])
      .html(function (d) {
          var tooltipHTML = "<span class = 'name'>" + d.Name + "</span><br/>" + d.Year + "<br/>" + d.Nationality;
          if (d.doping !== "") {
              tooltipHTML += "<br/>" + d.Doping;
          } else {
              tooltipHTML += "<br/>No doping allegations";
          }
          return tooltipHTML;
      });
    /*
   create svg element then append height and width and g which act as a container
   */
    var svg = d3.select("body").
      append("svg").
      attr({
          "width": width + margin.right + margin.left,
          "height": height + margin.top + margin.bottom
      }).
    append("g").
      attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.right + ")");

    //call toolTip
    svg.call(toolTip);
    // Draw xAxis
    svg.append("g")
     .attr("class", "x axis")
     .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
     .call(xAxis).append("text")
     .attr("x", 300)
     .attr("y", 35)
     .attr("dy", ".35em")
     .style("text-anchor", "middle")
     .text("Minutes Behind Fastest Time");;
    //Draw yAxis
    svg.append("g")
     .attr("class", "y axis")
     .call(yAxis)
     .append("text")
     .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
     .attr("x", 0)
     .attr("y", -35)
     .attr("dy", ".35em")
     .style("text-anchor", "end")
     .text("Ranking");

    /*
    create bar or bind data
   */
    //bind data
    svg.selectAll("circle")
      .data(data)
   //enter data
    .enter().
        append("circle")
   //update data
      .attr("class", "circle")
      .attr("cx", function (d) { return xScale(d.behind); })
      .attr("cy", function (d) { return yScale(d.Place); })
      .attr("r", 8)
      .attr("fill", function (d) {
          if (d.Doping == "") {
              return "green";
          }
          return "red";
      })
      .on('mouseover', toolTip.show)
      .on('mouseout', toolTip.hide);
    // Creating labels
    svg.selectAll("text")
                 .data(data)
                 .enter()
                 .append("text")
                 .text(function (d) {
                     return d.Name;
                 })
                 .attr("x", function (d) {
                     return xScale(d.behind - 5);
                 })
                 .attr("y", function (d) {
                     return yScale(d.Place - (-0.3));
                 })
                 .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
                 .attr("font-size", "11px")
                 .attr("fill", "black");
});
```

```css
svg {
  margin-top:50px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  background-color:antiquewhite;
}
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.bar {
  fill: orange;
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: orangered ;
}
.d3-tip {
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
/* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
.d3-tip:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  content: "\25BC";
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Style northward tooltips differently */
.d3-tip.n:after {
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
/*Do Not Change*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>ScatterPlot</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="../Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../Scripts/d3/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-tip/0.6.7/d3-tip.min.js"></script>
    <link href="demo.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
   
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="demo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[My Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/cannelflow/umc38kha/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use:

```
svg.selectAll("text")
```

There's other `text` nodes in your SVG (on the axis, for instance) and you are selecting things you don't really want.  Instead, use a class:

```
svg.selectAll(".label")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .attr("class", "label")
  ...
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/umc38kha/2/).